# Inside TWIG Template, how to determine if a paraph is empty or not

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraph called "Square cta" that I'm using like an old field collection.  It has 2 fields in it - a text field (field_cta_text), and an Image (field_square_cta_image).

I have a content type called "Show Page" in which I will upload an image and put in the cta text for.

I then have a view that shows all of the show pages and I reference the square_cta in my template - node--view--seasons.html.twig - like so

```
<a href="{{ url }}">{{ content.field_square_cta }}</a>
```

This works great for displaying the image inside the field_square_cta for the show and it acting as a link back to the Show Page node it's in.

Where I am having trouble, is not all shows have the field_square_cta populated.  For those show pages, I want to just display the of the node instead.  I have been unable to figure out how to write my if logic to determine if the field_square_cta is undefined.

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
{%  if content.field_square_cta %}
  <a href="{{ url }}">{{ content.field_square_cta }}</a>
{%  else %}
  <h1><a class="title" href="{{ url }}">{{ label }}</a></h1>
{% endif %}
```

The conditional is always going with the if, never the else, even when I don't have any data inside the content.field_square_cta.  I have been unable to determine the proper syntax for checking if that is empty or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of checking for the field, check for the first value of the field `{%  if content.field_square_cta.0 %}`

Comment: I have tried this as well and still always getting a positive when I'm expecting it to be empty

Comment: It sounds like maybe, with paragraphs, an "empty" paragraph gets saved with the node even if there is no content in the paragraph (https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/2459881) that might be why the is empty check is not wokring.  Not sure how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

This works if you know a field in the paragraph must be set for it to be considered "non-empty". Look at the entity the first item points to and check it's a required field.

```
{% if node.field_square_cta.0.entity.field_required.value %}
  {# Print the wrapping element, iterate through the paragraphs, do some stuff #} 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use the node object to check whether the field is not empty.

```
{% if not node.field_square_cta.isempty %}
```

Comment: I have tried {% if not node.field_square_cta.isempty %} and {% if not node.field_square_cta is empty %} and neither is working.  They both are giving false positives - meaning when I expect the field is empty, it is behaving as if it is not - the same that was happening to me on my initial post.

Comment: if there is an issue with the empty check of the field (you've mentioned in a comment to the question), then this would only apply to the code of this answer, because the code in the question checks only if there is a render array present, which always is, also if the field is really empty.

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had to go look at the fields inside the paragraph to determine if they were empty or not, as the paragraph always returned an empty array.  This is the code I used.

```
{% if content.field_square_cta.0['#paragraph'].field_square_cta_image.target_id %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to simply check the array length.

```
{% if node.field_square_cta.value|length > 0 %}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. There is always at least one empty item in the array